# Program is freezing on Windows API call to mouse_event

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to code an auto clicker bot, but I don't know why the program is blocking when i run it. This happens when the program enters `cliquer()`.

Yes I'm a student so I am a beginner, and indeed I'm French if you're asking.

Thanks for giving me an answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void cliquer();

int main()
{
    time_t time_to_run;
    time_t ac_time;
    time_t time_left;

    time(&ac_time);                                                     // Actualiser le temps

    cout << "Hello, wanna cheat on Voltaire ?" << endl;
    cout << "For how much time do you want to run it (s) ?" << endl;
    cin >> time_to_run;

    time(&ac_time);                                                     // Actualiser le temps

    time_to_run = ac_time + time_to_run;                                // Le temps à executer =  temps actuel + temps demandé

    while(ac_time < time_to_run)
    {
        time(&ac_time);                                                 // Actualiser le temps

        time_left = time_to_run - ac_time;



        //if(time_left <= 18000)                                          // Si supérieur à 5min
        //{
            cout << "TIME LEFT : " << time_left << endl;
        //}

        Sleep(100);

        cliquer();
    }

    return 0;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void cliquer()
{
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 957, 396, 0, 0);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 957, 396 , 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: Here, after researching your problem a little more I realized `mouse_event` is a WinAPI call. See if [this MS Forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/86dcf918-0e48-40c2-88ae-0a09797db1ab/how-can-i-do-virtual-mouse-click?forum=winforms) helps

Comment: I added SetCursorPos(957, 396); in the function "cliquer()" and my cursor moves and click but nothing happend next... :/

Comment: You may want to try to sleep between mouse down and up.

Comment: What happens if you get rid of the loop and just call `cliquer()` once?

Comment: Nah adding a Sleep(100); between mouse down and up didn't work as i expected.

Comment: If i call "cliquer()" just once it works but it's when i want to put it in a loop that it doesn't work.

Comment: I found an answer, it worked with 5 seconds but it took 11s to run... i guess there is a problem with the time loop in my program. I will work on it and post a corrected version in order to explain why it didn t worked so well to people seeking a correct auto clicker code.

Comment: The mouse position is expressed in twips. Use the [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) function instead.

Comment: @jim: `mouse_event` and `SendInput` use the same unit. Neither one is twips. It's either device pixels, or normalized device pixels, controlled by the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag.

Comment: @IInspectable  :) I know. That was kind of a pun. You know where/when Twips were used. You may read it as *ancient/deprecated/kindof funny*. *«(...) All measures will be expressed in furlong per week (...)»*

Comment: @jim: Maybe that was the intent. But with twips [being used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setmapmode) to this day, it easily turns into misinformation, even if not intentional.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for freezing is that your mouse focus is in the console. You can add `ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MINIMIZE)` to minimize the console, so as to avoid freezing.

And [mouse_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event) is out of date. Please use [SendInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput).

This is a sample you can refer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

time_t time_to_run;
time_t ac_time;
time_t time_left;
HWND hwnd;

void autoclick()
{
    INPUT input[2];
    ZeroMemory(input, sizeof(INPUT) * 2);
    input[0].mi.dx = input[1].mi.dx = 945;
    input[0].mi.dy = input[1].mi.dy = 500;
    input[0].type = input[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

    time(&ac_time);
    time_to_run = ac_time + time_to_run;

    while (ac_time < time_to_run)
    {
        time(&ac_time);                                                 // Actualiser le temps

        time_left = time_to_run - ac_time;
        cout << "TIME LEFT : " << time_left << "s"<<endl;
        SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
        Sleep(100);
    }

}

int main()
{
    hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    cout << "Hello, wanna cheat on Voltaire ?" << endl;

    while (1)
    {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE);
        cout << "For how much time do you want to run it (s) ?" << endl;
        cin >> time_to_run;
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_MINIMIZE);
        autoclick();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Yohann BENECH hi, does this answer useful to you? If you have any problem, please feel free to ask me:)